# Extracting structured data from semi structured data

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, pandas, text-mining, text-classification

I want to use machine learning and NLP to convert semi-structured data in text files to structured data by predicting the patterns in the files and splitting the fields for example if I have a text file that looks like this :

Input :

```
2021565267MALL1ETAGE ZARA1st FLOOR 2345561
2022565267MALL2ETAGE ZARA1st FLOOR 2345561
2022565267ANFAPLACE2ETAGECOFEESHOP2345561
20225652634ANFAPLACE2ETAGE 2345561
```

Desired Output :

```
2021565267,MALL1ETAGE ZARA1st FLOOR,2345561
2022565267,MALL2ETAGE ZARA1st FLOOR,2345561
2022565267,ANFAPLACE2ETAGECOFEESHOP,2345561
20225652634,ANFAPLACE2ETAGE,2345561
```

The semi-structured files are not fixed-width so we can not just add col specification in pandas like this ( it can work for the first line for example ) :

```
col_specification =[(1, 10),.... ]
```

One of the approaches that I found online is to make a dictionary based on the occurrences of the words in the semi-structured file will that work in this situation if so how can I implement something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I am making the following assumptions:

1. The first column of numbers is the first few digits/numbers in each line
2. The last column of numbers is the last few digits/numbers in each line
3. So, in the second column, texts like `MALL1ETAGE ZARA1st FLOOR` should not have numbers in the front or end. So, `20215652671MALL1ETAGE ZARA1st FLOOR 2345561` will be interpreted as `20215652671, MALL1ETAGE ZARA1st FLOOR, 2345561` and NOT `2021565267, 1MALL1ETAGE ZARA1st FLOOR, 2345561`

To this end, you can use the following that makes use of regular expression to capture the first and last group of numbers:

```
import re

re.findall("^([0-9]+)(.*?)([0-9]+)$", "2021565267MALL1ETAGE ZARA1st FLOOR 2345561")
# [('2021565267', 'MALL1ETAGE ZARA1st FLOOR ', '2345561')]
```

Applying `strip()` to each of the result removes the trailing whitespace to get the output you desire.